# How to change form with animation css in php code

Tags: php, jquery, css

So, i have forms and php code. I know how change form with button click 
*(by the way, animation does not work if the button is in the form. But if the button in outside of the form, it works, but it doesn't matter.)*

Like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
    $('#btn_1').click(function(){
    $('#formsss').toggleClass('flipped')
});
</script>
```

But I do not know how to make the animation turn on through the condition code in php

```
<div id="formsss">
        <div id="form_1">
            <h3>Form 1</h3><br>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input name="input1" value="<?php echo $_POST[input1]; ?>">
<br>
                    <?php

                    if ( isset($_POST['clicked_btn_1']) )
                    {

                        $errors = array();
                        if (trim($_POST['input1'] == ''))
                        {
                            $errors[] = 'Enter text';
                        }

                        if (R::count('test', 'input1 = ?', array($_POST['input1'])) > 0)
                        {
                            $errors[] = 'Such data is already in the database';
                        }

                        if (empty($errors))
                        {

                            // SWITCH ON FORM 2 .... HOW?????

                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION['input1'] = $_POST['input1'];

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<div style="color: red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                <button id="btn_1" type="submit" name="clicked_btn_1">Button 1</button>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div id="form_2">
            <h3>Form 2</h3><br>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input name="input2" value="<?php echo $_POST[input2]; ?>"><br>
                <?php

                if ( isset($_POST['clicked_btn_2']) )
                {

                    $errors = array();
                    if (trim($_POST['input2'] == ''))
                    {
                        $errors[] = 'Enter text';
                    }

                    if (R::count('test', 'input2 = ?', array($_POST['input2'])) > 0)
                    {
                        $errors[] = 'Such data is already in the database';
                    }

                    if (empty($errors))
                    {
                        // put in a database of two forms

                        $test = R::dispense('test');
                        $test->input1 = $_SESSION['input1'];
                        $test->input2 = $_POST['input2'];
                        R::store($test);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<div style="color: red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <button id="btn_2" type="submit" name="clicked_btn_2">Button 2</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

css animation

```
#form_2{
-moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
-o-transform: rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
transform: rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

#form_2, #form_1 {
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-transition: .6s;
-webkit-transition: .6s;
-o-transition: .6s;
transition: 600ms 0ms;
transition-delay: 0.1s;
-o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
-moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

#form_2 {
bottom: 20px;
top: 359px;
left: 20px;
right: 20px;
}

#form_2, pre {
position: absolute;
}

/*************************************************/

.flipped#formsss {
overflow: hidden;
}

.flipped #form_1 {
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
-o-transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
}

.flipped #form_2 {
-moz-transform: rotateY(0)scale(1);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(0)scale(1);
-o-transform: rotateY(0)scale(1);
transform: rotateY(0)scale(1);
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
z-index: 5;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: in which php condition do you want to start animation in page load ?

Comment: @bRIMOs At the start Form 1, when I press button 1, the condition is checked and if true, then the form animation occurs, form 2 appears

Comment: which condition here in your code php ? just to know where to put the conditional code

Comment: @bRIMOs Where there is a comment "SWITCH ON FORM 2"

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the flip annimation on startup just add the bellow script output inside the condition inisde the php code :

```
if (empty($errors)) {

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['input1'] = $_POST['input1'];
   // SWITCH ON FORM 2 .... HOW ?? , bellow code will switch :)
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    //the above will be executed after dom load
    echo "$( function(){  $('#formsss').toggleClass('flipped');  })";
    echo "</script>";

}
```

Comment: if you want to make a timer to trigger this last by example 2sec after dom load use setTimeout function